# Game Design Issue: Special items implementation

Tags: game-design, game-mechanics

I have a Match Two game similar to the bejeweled board. I am rewarding the player on speed of score. If he scores X in Y time , he gets a bomb. The time window is not rolling but discreat.

I check what the users score was in last X seconds after every Y seconds and reward him. The issue is the reward is a bomb which explodes 9 tiles. (I've dumbed down the score of the tiles exploded by bombs) Now that score will be counted in the next user score check and if the user made of more pair he will be given another bomb and this continues.

So once the user gets a bomb it's very easy to get it again and keep getting it. Which ruins the uniquness of the bomb. If I say hey let's not count the score because of the bomb that way the user will have to start all over again to get a bomb and if we have Z types of bombs one better than the other it would be impossible for the user to get all the bombs. If the score keeps on restarting.

I'm having a hard time finding the middle ground in it. Any ideas?

Also for special items, what seems to be better roll over time windows or static time windows?

Comment: What's wrong with not counting the tiles blown up with bombs?

Comment: Having the user to start over from zero score to get the next bomb. If there are X types of bombs user will always get the first bomb in Y seconds.

Comment: If you have some existing logic into which a new one doesn't fit, you can change either one of them. Just break it down into pieces on paper and you'll see what options you have (or you will see more of them than you previously thought there were).

Comment: Your question is not very clear to me. You say you require some positive feedback, getting a bomb should make it easier to reach the next reward, but you also want to avoid this feedback, because getting a bomb should not make it easier to get another. You can't have it both ways, so unless I am not understanding the mechanics correctly, I think you should reconsider your reward schedule.

Comment: Special items should be something you work hard for and get rewarded accordingly. They should be rare at the same time depend on the skill of the person.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution to this problem might be to gradually decrease the amount of time allowed for the player to get the required score and/or gradually increase the score required to get a bomb for a short period of time.

For instance, if a player earns a bomb, and the score of that bomb contributes to the combo score of the next time window, that time window will be shorter and the combo score required to earn the next bomb will be larger. After that time window elapses, the required time and combo score could be reset.

Answer (score 2):

> So once the user gets a bomb **it's very easy to get it again and keep
>   getting it. Which ruins the uniquness of the bomb**. If I say hey let's
>   not count the score because of the bomb that way the user will have to
>   start all over again to get a bomb and if we have Z types of bombs one
>   better than the other it would be impossible for the user to get all
>   the bombs. If the score keeps on restarting.

You could make it so that after a player gets a specific kind of bomb, he can't unlock the same bomb again until Z seconds have passed.  Thus, the player could still utilize the bomb to gain enough score to gain other types of bombs, but wouldn't continuously just keep getting the same one he used.